# jQuery UI Autocomplete pass additional data on request/response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQ UI Autocompletebox widget.

Here's the jQ that utilizes the ACB:

```
$('.drug-name').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax('/Drugs/JsonIndex/',
      {
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { searchBy: request.term },
        success: function (data) {
          response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return { value: item.Name, label: item.Name };
            /*1****************/
          }));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            /*2****************/
        },
        messages: {
          noResults: '',
          results: ''
        },
        _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
            /*3****************/ 
          return $('<li>')
                    .html(item.label)
                    .prop('title', item.description)
                    .data('drug-id', item.value)
                    .appendTo(ul);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

I've marked those spots I'd like to talk about:

1. The `data` argument received from the request contains the properties `Id`, `Name` and `Description`. I want the generated `li`s to use the `Name` as display value, the `Description` as tooltip (`title="Description"`), and the `Id` to be set to an additional data field
2. When an element is then selected, I want to set a hidden field with the selected item's Id
3. I thought about setting it with this function but first I can't figure a way to pass another structure other than jQ's normalized value and label one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after researching some, I found out that the `_renderItem` snippet should be attached as follows:

```
$('.drug-name').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax('/Drugs/JsonIndex/',
      {
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { searchBy: request.term },
        success: function (data) {
          response($.map(data, function (item) {
            return { 
                     value: item.Name,
                     label: item.Name,
                     description: item.Description,
                     id: item.Id
                   };
          }));
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
        },
        messages: {
          noResults: '',
          results: ''
        }        
      });
  }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $('<li>')
          .html(item.label)
          .prop('title', item.description)
          .data('drug-id', item.id)
          .appendTo(ul);
};
```